# Minimal element of a set in (ZFC)

Tags: set-theory

Let $\langle B, \le_B \rangle$ be a well ordered set. 
Let $\langle ^B\!\beta, \preceq \rangle$ be the set consisting of all functions from $B$ to the orinal $\beta$. 
We define $\prec$ as follows:
$$f \prec g\ \longleftrightarrow\ (\exists b \in B)((\forall c \in B)(c <_B b \Rightarrow f(c) = g(c))\ \&\ f(b) < g(b)).$$
I have to show that every non-empty subset of $^B\!\beta$ has least element. 

And my attempt: 
Suppose there is a non-empty subset $C \subseteq ^B\!\beta$, such that $C$ has no least element. This means that 
$(\forall g \in C)(\exists f \in C)(f \prec g)$. 
$f \prec g \longleftrightarrow\ (\exists b \in B)(f(b) < g(b))$, so we get 
$(\forall g \in C)(\exists f \in C)(\exists b \in B)(f(b) < g(b))$. 

Okay, now let's do the same thing for f, e.g. 
$(\exists h \in C)(\exists y \in B)(h(y) < f(y))$. 

And here I got stuck. I want to continue this process and get that $..<..< h(y) < f(y) < f(b) < g(b)$, which is an infinite decreasing sequence of ordinals. But each ordinal is well ordered, so such sequences does not exist. Contradiction! 
But, I don't know how to get that $f(y) < f(b)$, e.g. how to compare these.

Comment: **Hint:** You wrote $f \prec g \longleftrightarrow\ (\exists b \in B)(f(b) < g(b)),$ but that's not true.  Go back and look at the definition of $\prec$ again; $b$ is supposed to be the *earliest* position at which $f$ and $g$ differ.

Comment: @MitchellSpector I don't understand, this is just from the definition of the relation?

Comment: The definition is $f \prec g\ \longleftrightarrow\ (\exists b \in B)((\forall c \in B)(c <_B b \Rightarrow f(c) = g(c))\ \&\ f(b) <_B g(b)).$  The part $(\forall c \in B)(c <_B b \Rightarrow f(c) = g(c))$ is essential.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Okay, but I still don't get how prove the thing I want. Could you write a bit more detailed comment to help me?

Comment: The statement that you're trying to prove isn't true.  You can find a counterexample with $B=\beta=\omega.$  If this was an exercise or homework problem, did you omit some condition?  (Maybe $B$ is supposed to be finite?)

Comment: I just posted a counterexample as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each natural number $n$, let $X_n$ be the set $\mathbb{N}$ with the number $n$ removed from it. Then consider the collection $A = \cup_{i 
\in \mathbb{N}} X_i$.

Then the set $A$ has no smallest element in the ordering.

Proof idea: for all $n$ we have $A_{n+1} < A_n$ since the first $n - 1$ elements of both sets are equal, and the $n$'th element of $A_{n+1}$ is $n$, which is smaller than the $n$'th element of $A_n$, which is $n + 1$.

So then $A_1>A_2>A_3> \dots $

Answer (score -1):

This isn't true.  For a counterexample, set $B=\beta=\omega,$ and define $f_n\colon\omega\to\omega$ by letting

$$f_n(k)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{ if }k<n,\\
1,&\text{ if }k\ge n.
\end{cases}$$

Then $$f_0 \succ f_1 \succ f_2 \succ \dots,$$

so $\{f_n \mid n\lt\omega\}$ is a non-empty subset of $\omega^\omega$ with no $\prec$-least element.